# How do i get user key(google app)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do I get user key? I am trying like this

```
 user = User.get_by_auth_id('k')
 print user.key
```

Its displaying 1. But that key entity is very long. 
I am looking for `ag5kZXZ......`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using google.appengine.ext.db or google.appengine.ext.ndb ?

if your are using the standard db module it should be

```
print str(user.key())
```

i think with ndb your could get it with:

```
print user.key.urlsafe()
```